# How to work around "that email address has already been used" error?

Tags: users, errors

The following error may occur if a previous registration remains pending with a conflicting email address.

> That email address has already been used. Please check your inbox for
>   an activation email. It will become available in a couple of days if
>   you do nothing.

The related username error looks like the following.

> That username is currently reserved but may be available in a couple of days.

Answer (score 6):

When I add a new user with a different email address, I get the error message: That username is currently reserved but may be available in a couple of days.

For me, I removed the row from the database in the table wp_signups where user_login equaled the username. Essentially:

```
delete from wp_signups where user_login = 'abc';
```

Then I was able to re-add the user.

Edit suggestion by @aubreypwd:
Additionally, admins (network admins only in an MU or network install) have the option to add users without sending an email. If you check that option, it avoids this process.

Comment: I would also add details to make sure and next time you try and add the user, to click "bypass email confirmation" to complete this answer. This is a very good technical answer and the route I use.

Answer (score 3):

1. Login as WordPress administrator
2. Navigate to add a new user
3. Check box to bypass email confirmation
4. Add the user with a different email address
5. Edit the user's email address to the desired result

For the similar username error, see [How can I un-reserve a pending username registration?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/160633/how-can-i-un-reserve-a-pending-username-registration)

The timeout period is 2 days following a conflict, and trac tickets to clarify this process currently exist [here](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/31127) and [here](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/31127).

Answer (score 1):

To work around the "that email address has already been used" error, we can create a plugin that effectively bypasses the check. The plugin will work in three parts, utilizing three different hooks.

[`pre_user_login`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_user_login/) filters a username after it has been sanitized. We'll use this hook to grab the user, of particular interest is the email.

[`pre_user_email`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_user_email/) filters a user’s email before the user is created or updated. We'll use this hook to modify the email to some random characters.

[`user_register`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/user_register/) fires immediately after a new user is registered. We'll use this hook to manually update the user email after the user is registered.

```
add_filter( 'pre_user_email', [ new wpse_212671(), 'pre_user_login' ] );
class wpse_212671 {
  protected $user;
  public function pre_user_login( $user ) {
    $this->user = $user;
    if( isset( $user[ 'ID' ] ) || ! get_user_by( 'email', $user[ 'user_email' ] ) {
      return $user;
    }
    add_filter( 'pre_user_email', [ $this, 'pre_user_email' ] );
    add_action( 'user_register',  [ $this, 'user_register' ] );
  }
  public function pre_user_email( $email ) {
    return $this->generate_random_string();
  }
  public function user_register( $user_id ) {
    global $wpdb;
    $table = $wpdb->prefix . 'users';
    $wpdb->query( $wpdb->prepare(
      "UPDATE %s 
      SET user_email = %s
      WHERE user_login = %s", 
      $table,
      $this->user[ 'user_email' ], 
      $this->user[ 'user_login' ]
    ) );
  }
  //* Code slightly modified from http://stackoverflow.com/a/13212994/6077935
  protected function generate_random_string( $length = 40 ) {
    return substr( str_shuffle( str_repeat( 
      $x='0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ',
      ceil( $length / strlen( $x ) )
    ) ), 1, $length );
  }
}
```

Comment: So will this allow me to remove a user completely without having to go into the DB and manually remove the users from wp_signups?

Answer (score 1):

There is a useful plugin called "User Activation Keys" which adds a menu item to the Network Users interface:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-activation-keys/

This allows for editing/deleting/approving user activation requests and subsequently reserved email addresses/usernames.

Comment: Worked with my very old WordPress 4.8, with PHP 5.4

Answer (score 1):

If you're comfortable working directly in MySQL and would rather not write code or install a plugin just for this task, you can fix this issue pretty simply.

Inside your site's MySQL database, there will be a table named `{ $wpdb->prefix }_signups`, where `$wpdb->prefix` is whatever prefix you have configured WP to use for its database datables. (By default, that is `wp_`.)

Query that table by the email address that's locked up to find the signup record for it:

`SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->prefix}_signups WHERE user_email = '{ email address }';`

That should bring back the record of the signup attempt for that email address. Then just DELETE that record from the table, and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Unconfirmed](https://wordpress.org/plugins/unconfirmed/) plugin.

Unconfirmed creates a Dashboard panel under the Users menu (Network Admin > Users on Multisite) that shows a list of unactivated user registrations. For each registration, you have the option of resending the original activation email, or manually activating the user.